# Print a dataframe after loading data from a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, sorry if this is already answered I've been looking for the answer but I didn't find a way to solve my problem and thank you for your amazing support. I am getting into Python and all the information I found here is very useful.

```
    #Define a function to import data
def import_data(): 
    data = pd.read_csv('Sales_Transactions_Dataset_Weekly.csv',sep=';',index_col=0,header=0) 
    df=data.iloc[:,0:52]
    return df
```

I have a .csv file with time series in columns (w1,w2,w3...) and I want to keep only the first 52 columns in my data frame. To do that I did this function:

After that I cannot print my DataFrame, I'd like to use it in another function I created. but I always get the same error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-e6cb9dbb3286> in <module>
      1 import_data()
----> 2 print(df)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to set `df`

`df = import_data()`

Comment: Thank you!!
I forgot to assign it to df.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but the problem is that your function is returning the dataframe which you are not saving in a variable after function call. learn more about [Function Return in Python](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-return/)

So when you tried displaying the dataframe using variable `df` (which is local to the function `import_data()` ) you are getting error 'df' is not defined, which means it cannot find a variable called df in current scope. Read this link to learn more about [Scope In Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

To fix this issue simply do this

```
df=import_data() 

#import_data will return a dataframe which will be saved in df variable and then you can use this "df" variable to display your data   

df
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood where my error was. I have to assign the variable.

Comment: no problem, please do upvote the answer as it helps others knowing it was correct and helps new accounts grow Thank you